# image button click event not firing on all pages Site.master

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

I have a Site.master page with an onserverclick event which works fine when I load some .aspx pages but then on some of the pages the event in the Site.master page does not fire at all.
Really doesnt make sense and was hoping that someone could give me an indication as to why this is?

this is the button in the master page.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Pandora.Web.WebForms.SiteMaster" %>

<input type="image" runat="server" id="btnSearchFunction" src="Images/searchIcon.png" name="image" width="16" height="20"  onserverclick="btnSearchFunction_Click" />


protected void btnSearchFunction_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //code
    }
```

This is an example of a page where the event in Site.master does not want to fire

```
<%@ Page Title="TopicsPage" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TopicPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pandora.Web.WebForms.TopicPage" %>
```

Sorry if it all comes accross as a bit vague

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mysterious. My only thought here is that there is another javascript error on some of the pages that is stopping the onserverclick event from running i.e. the underlying __doPostback call.

I would run the pages that are at fault through firebug/chrome developer tool bar (etc..) and look on the console for javascript errors

**ALSO**

Just to try - i would change the HtmlControl to an ImageButton (i.e. a webcontrol) just to see if that makes any difference - changing onserverclick to onclick. I don't think this is the problem though to be honest

**AND**

I'm assuming that the pages that it doesn't work with are always the same pages (rather than it being truly intermittent). If so - on those pages just try including the same button direct on the page. Does it work then. It will help isolate it down to the master page if that genuinely is the root cause

Good luck

Comment: Yes, thats a good idea. Thanks. It happens on the same pages and it feels like a javascript scenario but no errors either(in Console)

Comment: No probs. Just incidently it doesn't have to be an error to stop the onclick from working. If there is other valid javascript in those pages wired into the button click event it could prevent the __doPostback from getting triggered. It's worth viewing source on those elements to check exactly what is wired in